# MS Chart: how to get selection range?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have the chart (axis X - dates, axis Y - numbers), data source is Dictonary.
How i can get data (or indexes) in selection range of chart?
e.g.
data:
10/10/2012 , 10
10/11/2012 , 11
10/12/2012 , 12
10/13/2012 , 13
10/14/2012 , 14

Then user select on chart range from 10/11/2012 to 10/13/2012, can i get X values from 10/11/2012 to 10/13/2012 ?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.cursor.selectionstart.aspx and it didn't work for me, but it sounds like the most reasonable thing. Perhaps it'll work for you? Let me know!

Comment: I have done something similar, check my [wall of text over there][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777087/how-to-retrieve-the-selected-range-in-the-net-winforms-chart-control/15777401#15777401