# How to get a right click mouse event? Changing EventArgs to MouseEventArgs causes an error in Form1Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

I have a method to detect the left click event that visual studio made by double clicking on the form.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Left click");
}
```

I want to have a right-click event by right-clicking on the same object.

I read online that you can use this switch:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right){MessageBox.Show("Right click");}
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left){MessageBox.Show("Left click");}
}
```

The trouble is that when I do `e.Button` it has has yields an error error:

> `System.EventArgs` does not contain a definition for `Button`...

So I fix this by changing the `EventArgs.e` to `MouseEventArgs.e`

But then there is a new error in Form1Designer where the event line is:

```
this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
```

The error says:

> No overload for `pictureBox1_Click` matches delegate `System.EventHandler`

How do I fix this? 
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should introduce a cast inside the `click` event handler

```
MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs) e;
```

Comment: Never known that you could cast an EventArgs to a MouseEventArgs. Could you give a reference about that?

Comment: No @Steve, I think it is undocumented feature. IIRC I found it when I peek it through reflector :)

Comment: This seems strange to me, but most of life does! Regarding using a mouse, I would  add a mouse Click event where it passes in MouseEventArgs then you get the button states from there. I have to admit I would not recommend the above as good practice, Just my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: For other readers: this undocumented feature is not available on all controls. This will work for PictureBox, but not for ListView, for example.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You are begging to be broken when something internal changes. Instead, you should use the solution below and handel MouseClick instead of Click.

Comment: It's rather called "polymorphism", not "terrible idea". :)

Answer (score 40):

You need `MouseClick` instead of `Click` event handler, [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx).

```
switch (e.Button) {

    case MouseButtons.Left:
    // Left click
    break;

    case MouseButtons.Right:
    // Right click
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to do it but I probably didn't do it right, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 25):

For me neither the MouseClick or Click event worked, because the events, simply, are not called when you right click.
The quick way to do it is:

```
 private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //do something here
        }
        else//left or middle click
        {
            //do something here
        }
 }
```

You can modify that to do exactly what you want depended on the arguments' values.

**WARNING:** There is one catch with only using the mouse up event. if you mousedown on the control and then *you move the cursor out of the control to release it*, you still get the event fired. In order to avoid that, you should also make sure that the mouse up occurs within the control in the event handler. Checking whether the mouse cursor coordinates are within the control's rectangle before you check the buttons will do it properly.

Comment: May be instead of using the **MouseUp** event use the **MouseDown** event so you don't have to worry about what you said on your warning.

Comment: @Pabinator The MouseDown is producing unnatural behavior. You expect the action to happen when you release the button, not when you press on it. The warning is given because the event does not work as it should. It is supposed to only fire if the cursor is on the control when you *release* the button. It must be a .NET glitch or something.

Answer (score 5):

Use MouseDown event

```
if(e.Button == MouseButton.Right)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use MouseClick event instead of Click

Comment: I tried that but i got an error, I probably didn't do it right, thanks anyway.

Comment: I wish MouxeClick event capture right mouse click reliably. but for .net 4.5 compiled with c# visual stuydio 2013 professtional, it always fails for button...

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely help Many!

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_ClickEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_ClickEvent e)
    {
        if(e.nButton==2)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition);
        }
    }
```

**[** e.nbutton==2 **]** *is like* **[** e.button==MouseButtons.Right **]**

Answer (score 0):

This code is true :

```
MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
if (me.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   //Right Click
else
   //Left Click
```