# System.EventArgs Doesn't contain the definition of Button - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mouseevent, buttonclick

I have a `DataGridView` on my winform and I am showing 5 columns and few rows in it, I want to add a functionality that if I right click on any row it displays me a menu to see more detail about that record.
But I am getting an error when I write `e.Button` that

> System.EventArgs Doesn't contain the definition of Button and no extension method button accepting the first argument of type System.EventArgs could be found (are you missing any directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: Button is in MouseEventArgs.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448346/how-to-get-a-right-click-mouse-event-changing-eventargs-to-mouseeventargs-cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of `DataGridView` actually provides a `MouseEventArgs` argument. You declared your `datagridview1_MouseClick` method only with `EventArgs`.

Change that to

```
protected void datagridview1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == ...
```

and it should work (in case you used `CellMouseClick` instead of `MouseClick`, use `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` instead of `MouseEventArgs`).

---

As a side note: you don't get a compilation error when you add your "wrongly" declared handler like `datagridview1.MouseClick += datagridview1_MouseClick`, because `MouseEventArgs` is derived from `EventArgs`, so the compiler has no problem with that assignment. The problem arises when you try to access the properties of a `MouseEventArgs` instance via `e` when `e` is declared as `EventArgs`, because `EventArgs` doesn't know the properties of the `MouseEventArgs` derivate.

---

*P.S.: Please post your code as text to your next question. It's better for us to read or to re-use for reproducing the error than an image. In that image, I can't see if you used the `MouseClick` or `CellMouseClick` event*

Comment: It is `MouseClick` but your answer worked for me (Y). Thanks for Explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate handler method should be using DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx