# Right Clicking Action for Windows Form Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

Some quick context: in this project we're using a Visual C# Windows Form project to recreate Minesweeper.

I am using an array of Cells (which inherit from Control.Button).

As extra credit, I want the user to be able to flag a cell like you can in the class version of the game. However, I can't get right-clicking to work.

When trying to find a solution, I read that you need to typecast the EventArg as a MouseEventArg, but that didn't solve my problem as right-clicking doesn't even trigger my click event.

Here's some paraphrased code:

```
namespace Project_5___Minesweeper_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class Cell : Button { /*Custom Cell-Stuff Goes Here*/ }

        Cell[,] board = new Cell[AXIS_LENGTH, AXIS_LENGTH]; //Axis Length is just the dimensions of the board (I use 10x10).

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AXIS_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < AXIS_LENGTH; j++)
                {
                    board[i, j] = new Cell();
                    //Set position and size
                    board[i, j].MouseClick += button_arrayClick; //button_arrayClick() is never called by a right-click. Code for it is below. I suspect this line of code has to do with right-clicks not class button_arrayClick().
                    groupBox1.Controls.Add(board[i, j]); //I'm containing the array of Cells inside of a groupbox.
                }
            }
        }

        private void button_arrayClick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Is prepared for handling a right-click, but never receives them.
        {
            Cell temp = (Cell)sender;
            MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            if (me.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //Stuff that happens on left-click
            } else {
                //Stuff that happens on right-click
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This is where I grabbed the [type-casting the event arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448346/how-to-get-a-right-click-mouse-event-changing-eventargs-to-mouseeventargs-cause) from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseClick` does not handle right clicks for buttons. You can use `MouseDown`.

```
board[i, j].MouseDown += button_arrayClick;
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works, I now have a functioning right click for my cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use the _MouseDown event instead.

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        { 
            //stuff that happen on right-click
        }
        else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            //stuff that happen on left click
        }
    }
```

[image: auto generate handler in Visual Studio 2013]

Comment: This would work normally, but since I'm use an array of buttons that aren't displayed in my design view, I have to use the method @JohnKoerner suggested.

Answer (score 0):

listen for MouseDown event

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```